# MacBook Pro can't get more than 2048 x 1152 on my QHD Dell monitor through Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter (4K capable)

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

Short story:

My MacBook Pro (Retina 13" Late 2012) can't run 2560 x 1440  on new QHD monitor (Dell S2719DM - Only has HDMI ports) through a 4K Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter.

Why and how to fix?

Long Story:

So before I bought this monitor I had bought a Lenovo that I got to work running 2560 x 1440 on my MacBook through DisplayPort (HDMI apparently only gets up to HD on this generation of MacBooks), but these Lenevo monitors have some bugs that creates a lot of problems with DisplayPort and QHD on Mac, so when DisplayPort failed on this monitor, I returned it and upgraded to a DELL S2719DM

When I got home from the electronics store after closing hours on Saturday (Sundays are closed around here) to my despair (I'm working on an important project this weekend), I found out that the monitor didn't have DisplayPort, only HDMI (which again won't give me 2560 x 1440 from HDMI port on my MacBook Pro). Since all stores were closed for the weekend, I found this private seller that sold a barely used 4K Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter [(this one here)](https://macally-europe.com/md-hdmi-4k) and drove a long way to buy it from him.

Then I get back home, ready to continue working on my project with deadline approaching and confident that this will surely work. I soon realized that the max resolution using this (and the high speed HDMI cable included with monitor) is 2048 x 1152.

What is wrong? Shouldn't the result have been the same as with Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort on my previous monitor? Does the Mac view this connection as HDMI and therefore limit the resolution as if I just directly used the HDMI port on the MacBook?